Control what can be uploaded in AEM sling
I was asked to restrict what can be uploaded in Adobe Experience Manager (author) - limit the size, content, name etc. As AEM is built on Sling, which has a REST-ful interface, almost everything can be done with HTTP requests. (Examples here: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/experience-manager-65/content/sites/administering/operations/curl#common-content-manipulation-aem-curl-commands)
The only practical way that I can see is adding some filtering on the Author Dispatcher, assuming that all the users connects with AEM via the dispatcher, not directly.
Is it possible to set some restrictions in AEM itself?
